# one subdirectory vs subsubsub...directory for storing files

Tags: php, file-upload, directory, filesystems

I am building an app that features files upload (imgs, vids).
and I read in an article, generate a uuid for the file name like `e5d9aa9e-c5d2-46f4-b929-11b0a553f9b5.jpg` then take the first few characters to create a subdirectories like `\e\5\d\e5d9aa9e-c5d2-46f4-b929-11b0a553f9b5.jpg` to save the file to prevent limitions in of one directory.

So I taught I could just take the first few characters and create one directory with no sub like `\e5d\e5d9aa9e-c5d2-46f4-b929-11b0a553f9b5.jpg`

Please which is the best options of these two method of storing files in a directory

- `\e\5\d\e5d9aa9e-c5d2-46f4-b929-11b0a553f9b5.jpg`

> the first few letters of the file is used to generate subsubdirectories

- `\e5d\e5d9aa9e-c5d2-46f4-b929-11b0a553f9b5.jpg`

the first few letters are used to generate just on directory to store the file